# How to remove whitespace from file and extract the corresponding indices from another file? - bash

Tags: python, regex, bash, awk, sed

I've three files:

**file1.txt**:

```
XYZ与ABC
DFC什么
FBFBBBFde
warlaugh世界
```

**file2.txt**:

```
XYZ 与 ABC
warlaugh 世界
```

**file3.txt**:

```
XYZ with abc
DFC whatever
FBFBBBF
world of warlaugh
```

`file2.txt` is a processed file from `file1.txt` with spaces. The lines of `file1.txt` aligns with `file3.txt`, i.e. `foobaristhehelloworld <-> XYZ with abc`.

The processing threw away lines from `file2.txt` due to some reason but what's more important is to retrieve the corresponding lines from `file3.txt` after processing.

How could I check for which lines have been removed in `file2.txt` and then produce a `file4.txt` that looks like this:

**file4.txt**:

```
XYZ with abc
world of warlaugh
```

I could do it with python but I'm sure there's a simple way with sed/awk or bash tricks:

```
with open('file1.txt', 'r') as file1, open('file2.txt') as file2, open('file3.txt', 'r') as file3:
    file2_nospace = [i.replace(' ', '') for i in file2.readlines()]
    file2_indices = [i for i,j in enumerate(file1.readlines()) if j in file2_nospace]
    file4 = [j for i,j in enumerate(file3.readlines()) if i in file2_indices]

    open('file4.txt', 'w').write('\n'.join(file4))
```

**How can i create file4.txt with sed/awk/grep or bash tricks?**

Comment: Why is `DFC` line missing from file2?

Comment: The processing script throws things away. Updated the question.

Comment: If you say `grep -f f1 <(sed 's/ //g' f2)` you will get the common lines between `f1` and `f2` (we remove spaces from `f2`). Then you can loop through them and compare with `f3`

Comment: the grep command is giving `grep: Unmatched ( or \(`

Comment: @alvas fedorqui's code has probably been cleaned when posting, it should be `$(` before sed (`$()` to get output of command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first remove spaces in `file2.txt` to make its lines like `file1.txt` :

```
sed 's/ //g' file2.txt
```

then use that as a pattern to match with `file1.txt`. do this using `grep -f` command and use `-n` to see line numbers of file1.txt which matches with the constructed pattern from `file2.txt` :

```
$ grep -nf <(sed 's/ //g' file2.txt) file1.txt
1:XYZ与ABC
4:warlaugh世界
```

now you need to remove any character after `:` to make a new pattern to matches with `file3.txt` lines:

```
$ grep -nf <(sed 's/ //g' file2.txt) file1.txt | sed 's/:.*/:/'
1:
4:
```

to add line number to each line of `file3.txt` use this:

```
$ nl -s':' file3.txt | sed -r 's/^ +//'
1:XYZ with abc
2:DFC whatever
3:FBFBBBF
4:world of warlaugh
```

now you can use the first output as a pattern to match with the second:

```
$ grep -f <(grep -nf <(sed 's/ //g' file2.txt) file1.txt | sed 's/:.*/:/')  <(nl -s':' file3.txt | sed -r 's/^ +//')
1:XYZ with abc
4:world of warlaugh
```

and to remove starting line numbers simply use `cut`:

```
$ grep -f <(grep -nf <(sed 's/ //g' file2.txt) file1.txt | sed 's/:.*/:/')  <(nl -s':' file3.txt | sed -r 's/^ +//') | cut -d':' -f2
XYZ with abc
world of warlaugh
```

finally save result to `file4.txt` :

```
$ grep -f <(grep -nf <(sed 's/ //g' file2.txt) file1.txt | sed 's/:.*/:/')  <(nl -s':' file3.txt | sed -r 's/^ +//') | cut -d':' -f2 > file4.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it similarly in a single call to awk:

```
awk 'FILENAME ~ /file2.txt/ { gsub(/ /, ""); a[$0]; next }
     FILENAME ~ /file1.txt/ && $0 in a { b[FNR]; next }
     FILENAME ~ /file3.txt/ && FNR in b { print }' file2.txt file1.txt file3.txt
```

You can also use two awks to avoid using the `FILENAME` variable:

```
awk 'FNR==NR { gsub(/ /, ""); a[$0]; next } 
    $0 in a { print FNR }' file2.txt file1.txt | 
awk 'FNR==NR { a[$0]; next } FNR in a { print }' - file3.txt
```

Use `> file4.txt` to output to file4.txt after either.

Basically it's

- take file2.txt and store it in an associative array after stripping spaces.
- store the line number form file1.txt compared to that associative array and store that in another associative array by file line number.
- test to see if the line number in file3.txt is in the 2nd associative array and print when there's a match.

Answer (score 1):

Loop through the original file, and look for the corresponding line in file2.
When the lines match, print the corresponding line from file3.

```
linenr=0
filternr=1
for line in $(cat file1.txt); do
   (( linenr = linenr + 1 ))
   line2=$(sed -n ${filternr}p file2.txt | cut -d" " -f1)
   if [[ "${line}" = ${line2}* ]]; then
      (( filternr = filternr + 1 ))
      sed -n ${linenr}p file3.txt
   fi
done > file4.txt
```

When the files are large (actually when the number of lines in file2 is large), you would like to change this solution, avoiding sed to go through file2 and file3 everytime. The solution would be less simple to write/understad/maintain...

Answer (score 1):

Looking once in every file can be done with diff and redirection of stdin.
This solution only works when you are sure they do not have a '|'-character:

```
#/bin/bash

function mycheck {
   if [ -z "${filteredline}" ]; then
      exec 0<file2.txt
      read filteredline
   fi
   line2=${filteredline%% *}
   if [[ "${line}" = ${line2}* ]]; then
      echo ${line} | sed 's/.*|\t//'
      read filteredline
      if [ -z "${filteredline}" ]; then
         break;
      fi
   fi
}

IFS="
"
for line in $(diff -y file1.txt file3.txt); do
   mycheck "${line}"
done > file4.txt
```